# MongoDB Client Side Field Level Encryption (CSFLE) Restricts Operations On Unencrypted Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My database contains 3 collections: "patients", "therapists", "subscriptions".

I've configured CSFLE on the db connection, providing a json schema which defines field level encryption **only** on the 'name' and 'email' fields in the 'patients' collection.

The field level encryption / decryption on the 'patients' collection works as expected.

However, now an unrelated aggregation query fails with **"MongoError: Pipeline over an encrypted collection cannot reference additional collections."**

This error occurs when executing an aggregation query on the 'therapists' collection, which includes a $lookup from the 'subscriptions' collection (not "over an encrypted collection" as the error suggests).

Neither 'therapists' nor 'subscriptions' are defined in the CSFLE json schema, and are not encrypted.
I don't understand why should this $lookup on unencrypted collections, lead to an error.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/security-client-side-query-aggregation-support/#unsupported-insert-operations)

> Automatic client-side field level encryption supports the $lookup and
> $graphLookup *only if* the **from** collection matches the collection on
> which the aggregation runs against (i.e. self-lookup operations).

While the limitation may be acceptable when dealing with the 'patients' collection, I don't think it is acceptable when dealing with other, non CSFLE, collections.

I know that I can create 2 separate MongoClient instances, one with CSFLE enabled, and one without, and use the non CSFLE client for the $lookup, but this would introduce extra complexity, and it doesn't seem like a clean and reasonable solution to me.

BTW, I'm using mongoose, but the behaviour is the same when using mongodb directly.

Would you say this is a bug with mongodb?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add an mcve demonstrating the problem please (I suggest with mongo shell) along with your server version.

Answer (score 5):

This turned out to be a bug with MongoDB..

Jira ticket:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-50092

This is a current limitation where using encrypted client assumes that it's necessary and doesn't allow $lookup into another collection.

Current workaround would be to use a non-encrypted client for such aggregations.

Comment: The issue is still not fixed and they are keeping it in backlog state.